# Drush or Drupal console command to list modules with security updates?

Tags: 8, drush, security, console

Is there a command for Drupal 8.x that shows available updates?

I added forms_steps 1.1 that has an SA and a security update required in the Web UI, which is saying to update to 1.2

[image: Web UI showing the there is a security update required]

I tried `drush pm:security` but it reports that there is no outstanding security.

```
root@d568732a8640:/app# drush pm:security
 [success] There are no outstanding security updates for Drupal projects.
```

I might have overestimated the capability of this command so I'm looking for alternatives to get both update and security update in the console. My goal with this is to add a schedule job in our CI that will report on those.

Comment: Drupal's core module "Update" sends you reports out of the box. You can configure it to send an email to given email addresses when a security update is available. Just ensure Drupal's cron runs regularly. That's all.

Comment: Maybe include the link to the issue you created on GitHub for reference: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/4189

Comment: Thanks for linking the issue.  Two things; one I'm not sure it's an issue so I opened this discussion here to look for alternatives and two I'm looking for something that can report in a CI project without requiring a live site.

Comment: And letting your CI site send mails?

Comment: We are aiming small for now as a first step we just want to create a badge in our project with the numbers of update, green 0 update, yellow 1 or more updates, red when 1 update or more is a security update. The badge would also link to the report. After this we might want to automate the creation of a ticket in gitlab and eventually with an MR ready to review.

Answer (score 3):

`drush pm:security` should be fine in listing Drupal modules with security updates.

There was a bug from the [drupal-composer/drupal-security-advisories](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-security-advisories/issues/18) project that resulted in not listing the forms_steps module and some other modules.  It was promptly fixed and now it works!